# What does version info mean in Visual Studio About Box?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

In Visual Studio 2005's About Box, the installed products have a (version?) number associated with them. A couple of our dev machines differ:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005
Version 8.0.50727.762  (SP.050727-7600)
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 2.0.50727 SP2

Installed Edition: Professional

...
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005   77626-009-1423927-41076
...
```

and

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005
Version 8.0.50727.762  (SP.050727-7600)
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 2.0.50727 SP2

Installed Edition: Professional

...
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005   77626-009-1423927-41911
...
```

Does anyone know the difference between 41076 and 41911?

All services packs and security updates are exactly the same on the 2 machines.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers look more like product ids (PID) that version numbers. If they are product ids, they are probably different because a different installation set/disk was used to install Visual  Studio on the two machines.